# OpenGL define colors using shaders

Tags: c++, opengl

I am learning OpenGL. At the moment i knew how to define primitives using VBO.
I implemented simple class Mesh and from this class some primitives like Square.
Now i wanted to learn good way to define colors. I am thinking about using shaders. My idea is to get something like this.

```
class ColorShader{
public:
    static GLuint red =  LoadShaders( "SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader", "red.fragmentshader" );    
};
```

But i am not sure is that good way to do. I think that plus of this method is that i will get 30-50% less memory for each triangle. But minus will be that i will need prepare more fragmentshaders.

VertexColor gives me more power to define objects but it consume more memory and I dont like idea settings colors and vertices in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set the color per object instead of per-vertex? I would go with sending a float4 value to the fragment shader for every object in a constant buffer (at least that is what it is called in DirectX). It is really simple and the most basic thing, really.

**Edit:** http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object They are called Uniform buffers in OpenGL.

The basic idea is that you declare a uniform variable in your shader, and get a pointer to it in your c++ code and upload 4 floats there every time you draw an object (or set once and the same color will be used for every object).

Comment: Yes. I am thinking about this but i didnt knew how to do that in opengl

Comment: Well, the link should help you and if you have any more questions, you probably would get more attention on gamedev.stachexchange.com. Good luck! ;)